# Add response header if the url ends with a specific snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to send the `Content-disposition "attachment"` header in the response, if the url ends with `mp3?dl`.

I want to do that in `.htaccess`.

I tried:

```
<FilesMatch ".mp3?dl$">
  Header set Content-disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

There is a WordPress site which adds some other stuff in `.htaccess`. If I add this snippet above at the end of the file, it doesn't make any change. If it's put at the top of the file, the whole website ends with a server error (500).

To check if the header is added I use `curl`:

```
$ curl -X HEAD -i 'http://example.com/files/audio/ping.mp3?dl'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 22 May 2016 13:34:00 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sun, 22 May 2016 13:21:51 GMT
ETag: "12a...2"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 76385
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

curl: (18) transfer closed with 76385 bytes remaining to read
```

How can I do this in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FilesMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch) applies to *files* and cannot match against a query string (`?dl`).

To check for a query string, you usually use [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `QUERY_STRING`, but there's no way to set a header with mod_rewrite, AFAIK.

You might try [`If`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#if) inside `FilesMatch` and check for the query string you desire, e.g.

```
<FilesMatch "\.mp3$">
    <If %{QUERY_STRING} == "dl">
        Header set Content-disposition "attachment"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score -1):

The [`FilesMatch` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch) accepts a **regex** as argument, so you'll need to escape the `.` and `?`, also add `.+` to match any filename, i.e.:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.mp3\?dl$">
  Header set Content-disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Based on your comments, you'll need to change `\?` to `\|`

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.mp3\|dl$">
  Header set Content-disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that... It's not working... Is it possible that it's because of Wordpress or so?

Comment: add `.+` in the beginning of the regex, check the update.

Comment: I tried that too, it's not working. I guess the problem is when matching the url: if I try to set a custom header (`X-Foo`, for example) for `.*`, that's working.

Comment: I think the problem appears when adding the `?` char. `FilesMatch ".mp3"` works fine.

Comment: Can you change the `?` to `|` ?

Comment: That works, but it's incorrect since `|` is special in RegExp. If I escape it, it doesn't add the headers...

Comment: Sure it is, I also didn't escape the `?` for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112615/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-pedro-lobito).